# What package rules do I need to set up in Kaspersky's Firewall to unblock Docker's “Shared Drive” feature?

Tags: firewall, anti-virus, docker

Kaspersky's Firewall blocks Docker's **Shared Drive** feature. [One possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42203488) to unblock the feature is to set the **vEthernet (DockerNAT)** network to `private`.

Is it possible to add a package rule to Kaspersky's firewall to unblock the feature? And in this case: How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

## Answer

**Yes, that is possible!**

## Solution

### The Rule

Just add a new **package rule** with the following configuration:
[image: Package Rule]

Translations that may be unclear otherwise:
Action: allow
Direction: inbound

### The Position

And sort it into your existing rule list at the following point:
[image: Package Rules]

Comment: Translation to English would be helpful...